# Is nuget.server supported on mono 3.2.6?

Tags: asp.net, mono, nuget, nuget-server

I am trying desperately to get a nuget gallery hosted on Apache with mono.  I have mono and apache configured and a new empty .net 4 web app with nuget.server created and copied to the linux server.  I got as far as getting the site up and running so the Default.aspx is displayed when browsing to the site.  However I can't get anything beyond that to work.  If I try to view available packages via the link on the main page (I copied some nupkg files into the Packages directory), I get the following error:

Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Details: Requested URL: /nuget/Packages

On IIS, the routemagic.dll seems to be the key in making the /nuget path work.  However that simply isn't happening in Mono.  I have no idea if this is simply not a supported service on mono or if I'm doing something wrong.

All permissions are correct.  I am calling mod-mono-server4 since the nuget.server was built with .NET 4.

Any help or direction would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it i made a little nuget server with php. It works on apache with mod_rewrite or IIS: http://www.kendar.org/?p=/dotnet/phpnuget :)

It supports security, push, odata queries, gallery and Nuget Package Explorer (https://npe.codeplex.com/) with 5 (five) minutes setup on Apache.

Actually it works on text file db and i'm doing the verifications for the MySql implementation.